# Wall switch not working anymore after ceiling fan replaced

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan, light

We had to replace a ceiling fan that previously operated from 2 switches (1 fan, 1 light). When we took it down all we saw was 1 main wire with a black, white & ground coming out of ceiling.  New fan with light hooked up (no remote so connections were grounds, whites and blue/black from fan to black in ceiling).  Now only 1 of the switches powers both light & fan and the other switch is dead.  I'm worried that there was another wire that we missed up in the ceiling that made both switches to operate independently before.
Is there a reason this would happen?

Comment: Turn off the breaker and pull both switches away from the box/es with the wires attached.  take pictures and post/edit them in your question.  I do believe you should have more than one main wire/cable  in the ceiling.

Answer (score 3):

Take a good look in the ceiling box. There's probably another wire, more that likely a red one up in there. It was probably jammed up in the box and when you removed the ceiling fan, the small light wire connection broke before pulling the other wire down with the rest.